# Netbeans will not treat JSP as Source Level 7

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, netbeans-7

I'm trying to run a `.jsp` page I made and keep encountering this error:

> type Exception report
>
> message Internal Server Error
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP
>
> PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 27 in the jsp file: /Drupalcheck.jsp
>      PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
>      diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
>        (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
>
> note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 logs.

The issue is that I have no clue why I'm getting it. I have the JDK set to 1.7 under Libraries and Source/Binary Format set to JDK 7 under sources.

I am using Netbeans as my IDE.

I've done everything from reinstalling Java to reinstalling Netbeans and have gotten nowhere.

Comment: can you post the code of line 27

Comment: Maybe you have configured some [Command Line Arguments](http://netbeanside61.blogspot.co.at/2009/02/using-command-line-arguments-in.html). Check that.

Comment: The line it's complaining about contains only "<%"

Comment: Also No Command line arguments are present

Answer (score 11):

In my opinion this has nothing to do with Netbeans, but rather with the application server in use. Is suspect you're using **Glassfish** or **Tomcat** as they are bundled together with Netbeans 7.

I had the **same problem with Apache Tomcat** and it boiled down to that Tomcat (Apache Jasper library) is using **Java 1.6 for JSP compilation by default**. You'll have to change the default configuration of the JSP servlet in `web.xml`. I added the following lines to the application's `web.xml`, **note** the two parameters **compilerSourceVM** and **compilerTargetVM**:

```
<!-- Jasper JSP configuration -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>fork</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>compilerSourceVM</param-name>
        <param-value>1.7</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>compilerTargetVM</param-name>
        <param-value>1.7</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- The mappings for the JSP servlet -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```