# Setting up Apache Tomee with jdk1.8 for ejb application

Tags: eclipse, java-8, apache-tomee

I am trying to set up apache tomee which could work on jdk 8.I am currently using Apache Tomee 1.5.0 plus,but when i run apache tomee,it runs and says "Started" in servers tab,but in console tab i always got

```
SEVERE: Compilation error
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFileReader.<init>(ClassFileReader.java:372)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1.findType(JDTCompiler.java:232)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1.findType(JDTCompiler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedReferenceBinding.resolve(UnresolvedReferenceBinding.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeFromTypeSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1335)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeFromVariantTypeSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1391)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeArgumentsFromSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1172)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeFromTypeSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1340)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.createMethod(BinaryTypeBinding.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.createMethods(BinaryTypeBinding.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.cachePartsFrom(BinaryTypeBinding.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.createBinaryTypeFrom(LookupEnvironment.java:688)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.createBinaryTypeFrom(LookupEnvironment.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.accept(Compiler.java:296)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedReferenceBinding.resolve(UnresolvedReferenceBinding.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getTypeOrPackage(PackageBinding.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getPackage(Scope.java:2379)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ParameterizedQualifiedTypeReference.internalResolveLeafType(ParameterizedQualifiedTypeReference.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ParameterizedQualifiedTypeReference.internalResolveType(ParameterizedQualifiedTypeReference.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ParameterizedQualifiedTypeReference.resolveType(ParameterizedQualifiedTypeReference.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.resolveTypeFor(SourceTypeBinding.java:1374)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.fields(SourceTypeBinding.java:699)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.faultInTypesForFieldsAndMethods(SourceTypeBinding.java:677)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.faultInTypes(CompilationUnitScope.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:468)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:459)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

dec 16, 2016 3:07:57 PM org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1 findType
SEVERE: Compilation error
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFileReader.<init>(ClassFileReader.java:372)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1.findType(JDTCompiler.java:232)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1.findType(JDTCompiler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedReferenceBinding.resolve(UnresolvedReferenceBinding.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getTypeOrPackage(PackageBinding.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getType(Scope.java:2472)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1006)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1258)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.resolve(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:468)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:459)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

dec 16, 2016 3:07:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception [Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Stacktrace:] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:469)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

dec 16, 2016 3:08:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception [Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Stacktrace:] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:469)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And also when i type localhost:8080 in browser i get following:

```
type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP:

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:469)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.30 logs.
```

My application doesn't have any jsp or servlets,it is EJB application,but it still says `Unable to compile class for JSP:` .Does anyone know solution to this problem?I searched the internet,answers were mostly that apache tomee and jre are not compatible,but i don't know what server to put since i should make ejb application(i also read that for ejb server should be apache tomee,not tomcat)..deos someone know which apache tomee server works with java 8?Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I have compiled the following from the internet,

```
TomEE Version | JavaEE Version  
--------------------------------
1.x           |     6   
7.x           |     7
```

> The J2EE 1.4 SDK is bundled with JDK 5 but... J2EE 1.4 requires JDK
>   1.4 or later. Java EE 5 requires JDK 5 or later. Java EE 6 requires JDK 6 or later (JDK 5 is at its EOL for 2+ months now).

So, J2EE version 7 needs Java 7 or later from what I understand. It is better that you try installing J2SE 7.

Please remember to do the following on the environment variables before you start the Tomee server

1. Java_home to J2SE 7
2. Update path environment variable to have /bin folder of j2se 7 available first

ref: http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-version-policies.html
ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2015780/258741

Answer (score 0):

There are several levels there.

High level is tomee 1.7 and 7.x support any java 7 or 8. Note TomEE 1.5 doesnt fully support java 8 whatever EE area it relates to.

Your error is related to JSP and jsp compilation has the java compilation config in the conf/web.xml file. Tomcat website seems off ATM but this stackoverflow link explains it too [Netbeans will not treat JSP as Source Level 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674097/netbeans-will-not-treat-jsp-as-source-level-7)